# Hazelcast embedded in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, hazelcast

I need to start Hazelcast within Tomcat without separate war-file.
So put hazelcast.jar into lib folder, hazelczast.xml somewhere... What next? 
Or it is not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First step was ok, just place Hazelcast lib and configuration inside the libs folder of Tomcat. Next thing, if you don't want a separate WAR file, is to build a small Valve class that starts up / shuts down the Hazelcast node.
The question is: What do you want to achieve with this, since for a practical use you will likely have to access the Hazelcast instance itself (which should be possible to place it as an attribute inside the HttpRequest).

Chris

Comment: Probably solved... 
I've added LifecycleListener implementation in Tomcat lib and registered it inside server.xml... inside I can create new node and close it. 
My profit - I have several web-applications under one Tomcat that use one hazelcast map, and I can have N tomcats with the same applications... 
so each Tomcat will have one hazelcast instance and all applications can be clients, no problems with re-deploy and extra memory.
I hope so :)

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible. But you need to have some piece of code calling Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance, or else nothing will happen.

Comment: In this case,How can I make sure that I will have only one instance of hazelcast per JVM? I am using hazelcast Spring and injecting HazelcastInstance bean into my service in my war application. But I have several .war applications and each one creates a seperate hazelcast instance.Although I have placed hazelcast libraries under $CATALINA_HOME/lib.

Answer (score 0):

I have found it easiest to just use Spring Boot and start hazelcast in the spring context.