# Access single hazelcast instance on same JVM

Tags: java, jvm, hazelcast

I have a Java web application (running on Tomcat) and would like to share data between two different contexts in the application.  I'd like to use hazelcast since I'm already using it for clustering purposes.

Is there a way to access a single hazelcast instance running on the same JVM (and the same port)?

I've trying accessing the instance using the instance name, but this doesn't seem to work.  For example:

```java
public class HazelcastTest1 {

    static public void main(String[] args) {
        Config config = new Config();
        config.getNetworkConfig().setPort(5701);
        config.getNetworkConfig().setPortAutoIncrement(false);
        config.setInstanceName("hztest");
        HazelcastInstance hz = Hazelcast.getOrCreateHazelcastInstance(config);
        Map<String, String> mp = hz.getMap("vcutest");
        mp.put("test1", "test1");
        System.out.printf("put item in map");
        while (true) {
        }
    }
}

public class HazelcastTest2 {

    static public void main(String[] args) {
        Config config = new Config();
        config.getNetworkConfig().setPort(5701);
        config.getNetworkConfig().setPortAutoIncrement(false);
        config.setInstanceName("hztest");
        HazelcastInstance hz = Hazelcast.getOrCreateHazelcastInstance(config);
        Map<String,String> mp = hz.getMap("vcutest");
        System.out.printf("map value = %s%n", mp.get("test1"));
    }
}
```

When I start the 2nd instance (with the 1st already running) the following exception is thrown:

> Exception in thread "main" com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastException: Port
>   [5701] is already in use and auto-increment is disabled. Hazelcast
>   cannot start.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hazelcast embedded in tomcat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22784347/hazelcast-embedded-in-tomcat)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve the same instance using `Hazelcast::getHazelcastInstanceByName` but this requires that the classes are visible to both webapp classloaders. You can achieve that by putting the JAR file inside the tomcat lib directory.

Apart from that, Hazelcast is not designed to run in a single instance mode, this will not perform well.

Comment: ah.. that makes more sense.  They need to be using the same JAR file.  I will probably take @Alex's advice and just start up separate nodes in the cluster.

Answer (score 1):

If you're deploying two separate WARs, despite the fact they are in the same JVM they are in isolated class loaders.

You should just consider them as separate JVMs and use Hazelcast as intended (have each web app join the cluster)

In this case, enable port auto increment, which should allow it to join the same Hazelcast instance